# Any .net Code Coverage Plugin for Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: .net, nunit, code-coverage

Can anyone please suggest me a good .net code coverage plugin for Visual Studio 2010 except dotCover? [dotCover 1.0 RC is buggy, it hangs VS 2010]
The VS2010's own coverage tool does not support nUnit tests. I want a plugin which supports nUnit tests also.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[TestDriven.net](http://www.testdriven.net/) is fairly popular and has code coverage built in. Of course, it does more than just code coverage.

[NCover](http://www.ncover.com/) is also fairly popular and is all about code coverage.

Both support NUnit tests.

Comment: TestDriven.net is excellent and its free for personal use. Thanks for the link.

Answer (score 1):

Made one: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=axodox1.AxoCover.
Although it is for VS2012+, so it might not help you. On the other hand it is really free (MIT).

Answer (score 0):

http://www.ncrunch.net/

Provides code coverage *and* continuous testing!

Comment: I've been using this for several months, and really like it still. However it's not free any more...